# Which function is triggered filterable attributes for the products on category page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, category-products, category-listing

Which function is triggered **when clicking on any filterable attributes for the products on category page** Magento 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the filter type.
All filter models implement the interface `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\FilterInterface`.
This interface contains (among others) a method called [`apply`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/FilterInterface.php#L48).

Depending on the attribute type, the method `apply` from different implementations of this interface is called.
For example, for price filter `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Price::apply()` is called.
For dropdown and multiselect attributes `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute::apply` is called.
For category filter `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Category::apply` 
and for decimal attributes `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Decimal::apply`